# Update trigger problem with two rows Updated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a trigger on a table by name : [OfficeAutomation_Letter]
 Updated table with every row update another time I
 But when the update command I run to two lines
 Will trigger an error
 I need to explain how each row of the aisle to develop

My trigger is:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Letter_UPD] ON [dbo].[OfficeAutomation_Letter] 
FOR UPDATE
AS

Declare @LetterID int
SELECT @LetterID = ID From Inserted

BEGIN           
    UPDATE OfficeAutomation_TempLetter 
    SET Archived = (Select Archive From Inserted ),
    OriginalNumber = (Select OriginalNumber From Inserted )
    WHERE LetterID = @LetterID          
END
```

Update my command is:

```
update OfficeAutomation_Letter set OriginalNumber=100 where ID in (3,4)
```

Visit The error is:

```
    Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when
 the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery 
is used as an expression.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triggers run once per statement, not once per row, and the inserted and deleted pseudo tables contain all affected rows.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Letter_UPD] ON [dbo].[OfficeAutomation_Letter] 
FOR UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE otl
    SET Archived = i.Archive,
    OriginalNumber = i.OriginalNumber
    FROM
      OfficeAutomation_TempLetter otl
         inner join
      inserted i
         on
            otl.LetterID = i.ID
```

So, in your original trigger, we have:

```
SELECT @LetterID = ID From Inserted
```

which is going to assign the ID of one of the affected rows (which one, who knows? - It is *not defined*)

And then

```
SET Archived = (Select Archive From Inserted ),
OriginalNumber = (Select OriginalNumber From Inserted )
```

which are the actual cause of the error you're seeing, because those selects on the right hand side are going to be returning multiple rows.